# Using the service manager in a custom Validator with Zend Framework 2 to get configurations

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm looking to retrieve the configuration for a validator that I"m setting on a form. Typically I could request this with the service manager, but I'm unclear on how to do this from deep in side a validator that is then going to be used on a Form.

The sort of skeleton code I have thus far is:

```
<?php
namespace Application\Validator;
use Zend\Validator\AbstractValidator;
use Auth\Model\LdapAdapter;


 class MyAccount extends AbstractValidator
    {


    const INVALID_ACCOUNT = 'invalid_account';


    protected $messageTemplates = array(
        self::INVALID_ACCOUNT => "'%value%' does not appear to be a valid account."
    );


    public function isValid($value)
    {
        $this->setValue($value);

        // What I'd like to get: 
        $ldapConfig = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Config')['ldap'];
        $ldapAdapter = new LdapAdapter($ldapConfig['server'], 
            $ldapConfig['backup_server'], 
            $ldapConfig['bind_dn'], 
            $ldapConfig['bind_password'], 
            $ldapConfig['search_dn']);
        $result = $ldapAdapter->getInfoForUser('sampleUsername');
        // do something with the result and then return 


        return true;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your validator depends on a configured LDAP adapter. Create a factory for your validator that retrieves the required adapter either by requesting it from the service manager or by creating it itself.

```php
namespace Application\Factory\Adapter;
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use Auth\Model\LdapAdapter;

class AccountValidator implements FactoryInterface
{

    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        // create configured LDAP adapter
        $ldapConfig = $serviceLocator->get('Config')['ldap'];

        $ldapAdapter = new LdapAdapter(
            $ldapConfig['server'], 
            $ldapConfig['backup_server'], 
            $ldapConfig['bind_dn'], 
            $ldapConfig['bind_password'], 
            $ldapConfig['search_dn']
        );

        // create validator
        $validator = new \Application\Validator\AccountValidator();

        // inject LDAP adapter dependency
        $validator->setLdapAdapter($ldapAdapter);

        return $validator;
    }
}
```

In this case the factory uses a setter to inject a configured LDAP adapter. Create this setter inside your validator class that stores the pointer to the adapter inside an attribute for later use inside the `isValid` method.

Don't forget to add the factory to your module config:

```php
[...]
'validators' => [
    'factories' => [
        'account' => 'Application\Factory\Adapter\AccountValidator',
    ],
],
```

Make sure you retrieve the validator from the service manager for the factory to kick in. When [creating a form via factory](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.form.quick-start.html#creation-via-factory), by [factory-backed form extension](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.form.quick-start.html#factory-backed-form-extension), etc. it does that for you.

Further reading: Concept of Dependency Injection, [Service Manager](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.service-manager.html)

Comment: If I breakpoint inside the `public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)` it never gets called and the $ldapAdapter is null as a result. I think I'm messing up something with the module.config.php / fundamentally not understanding how ZF2 works at that level.